# Loop through range and set values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to create a loop that goes through the range A1:A150 and sets the cell value to `=readmessage(Sheet2!A1)` with A1 changing dynamically with each cell. So with A2 it reads, Sheet2! A1.

```
function storeValue() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A150");
    for (var i = 1; i < range.length; i++) {
        range.setValue("=readMessage(Sheet2!"+range+")");
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, nothing is written into the cells in the range.

I'm guessing it's something to do with range.setValue.

Comment: What data structure is `range`?

Comment: The cells are empty. I actually just want the cell location. So literally just insert A1 or A2.

Comment: It looks that your are setting formulas not values, by the other hand, it's not clear to me what you mean by "with A1 changing dynamically with each cell", please add more examples of the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse values with formulas. For values there is setValue(value) and for formulas there is setFormula(formula).

By the other hand `var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A150");` assigns a Range object to the range variable. To get get it address use getA1Notation()

Answer (score 0):

This should work if I understood you correctly:

```
function storeValue(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; 

for (var i = 1; i < 150; i++) {
    range = sheet.getRange("A"+i);
    range.setValue("=readMessage(Sheet2! A"+i+")");
}  }
```

Otherwise comment below.